# Writing a PHP function that converts UK date to relative time

Tags: php

What would be the best way of converting UK date and time in the format:

`30/01/2013 13:30:06`

which is **d/m/Y H:i:s** in PHP noation to relative time (i.e. just now, few minutes ago, 30 minutes ago, 3 hours ago, 1 day ago.. and so on). I've seen several tutorials on the subject but they all revolve around creating functions without any clear explanations. I would appreciate some assistance on the matter.

Comment: To clarify, you want us to write tutorial about this with explanations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating relative time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculating-relative-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope This helps

```
function timeSince($ptime){
        $etime = time() - strtotime($ptime);

        if( $etime < 1 ){
            return 'less than 1 second ago';
        }

        $a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                    30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                    24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                    60 * 60             =>  'hour',
                    60                  =>  'minute',
                    1                   =>  'second'
        );

        foreach( $a as $secs => $str ){

            $d = $etime / $secs;     
            if( $d >= 1 ){

                $r = round( $d );
                return ' <font style="color:#0099ff"> ' . $r . ' ' . $str . ( $r > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago</font>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this with the datetime in the format 29/01/2013 13:20:42 but it comes up with 44 years ago

Comment: use this before: $ptime = str_replace('/', '-', $ptime);

Answer (score 2):

Use `mktime();` and `date();`

For example if you have a specific time in the format  `d/m/Y H:i:s`, and you want it as `d-m-Y H:s:i`, you would explode the time into chunks using `explode();` and then use `date(new_format, mktime(current_format_chunks))`

Answer (score 2):

Writing a custom function might help. Cut the string and convert to numbers. Use mktime() to create a timestamp, compare it to time() current timestamp and switch (case) through various relative time possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

`dd/mm/yyyy` needs to be changed to `dd.mm.yyyy` according to the [formatting rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) otherwise it will be treated as `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
$dateString = '30/01/2013 13:30:06';
$dateObject = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '.', $dateString));
```

with the optional addition of a [DateTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) as a second argument to the DateTime constructor.

Then you can do a [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) with the current date, and use [dateintervals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to get the relative time

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward and friendly way of parsing dates is the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) extension. It has a static method called [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date   = '30/01/2013 13:30:06';
$format = 'j/m/Y G:i:s';
$time   = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
echo $time->format('l dS F \'y at H.i.s');
```

The method takes a custom format and a date string. Because you can define the format yourself it is much easier than parsing it "manually".

In order to adjust the date you can use the `add()`, `sub()` and `modify()` methods:

```
$time->add(new DateInterval('P3DT5H')); // 3 days and 5 hours
echo $time->format('l dS F \'y at H.i.s');

$time->sub(new DateInterval('P9DT1H')); // 9 days and 1 hours
echo $time->format('l dS F \'y at H.i.s');

$time->modify('-1 year -35 days');
echo $time->format('l dS F \'y at H.i.s');
```

As you can see the `modify()` method is slightly easier to use. The two other methods use the `DateInterval` class and an awkward format. It is not difficult (just read the documentation and do as it says), but using actual words (i.e. "-3 days -7 hours") is easier to understand.